# How to identify a column with type citext in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a sample table with the first column defined as citext.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
nick CITEXT PRIMARY KEY,
pass TEXT   NOT NULL
);
```

When I try to execute the following query to get the column names and their data types, the data type of the nick column is returned as USER-DEFINED.

```
select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'users';

   column_name  |   data_type
1  nick         |   USER-DEFINED
2  pass         |   text
```

Is there any way I can find out by querying any table in postgreSQL if the column nick is of type citext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use column `udt_name` instead of `data_type`:

```
create type compfoo AS (f1 int, f2 text);

create table compfoo_table (cp compfoo);

select udt_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'cp';

-- drop table compfoo_table;
-- drop type compfoo;
```

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html)